# Visual Studio 2012 - coloring Jade code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, pug

Are there any easy&fast ways to add Jade code coloring and formatting to Visual Studio 2012 (with node plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

So, finally there is jade support since 1.0 beta release of [NodeJS tools for Visual Studio](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/)